# Geometry Nodes Flower Grow - How can I control the CURL of the flowers' petals individually

Tags: geometry-nodes

It is possible to realize instances and still control their rotation individually later on (or that's my impression, at least), like so (the individual petals are rotating, but not all at the same time):

[image]

[image]

BUT, is it possible to do that for the CURL or angle? I didn't manage to do that, the petals curl all at the same time:

[image]

[image]

this is not wanted. I'd like them to open up like in the upmost animation. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is that you would have to do the deformation of the petals after instantiation.

[image]

...I took the liberty of editing your file a bit, and included this modification:

[image]

The whole thing is structurally more a suggestion than an optimal solution. You may have to adjust some things and change them according to your wishes.

Unfortunately, I don't currently have the time to document all of this, so please bear with me if this response is so brief.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: It would be lovely to be able to instantiate  'live' parametric objects (in the OO Programming sense) in a GN tree, but I guess that breaks the model of a GN tree being a modifier (or a nested modifier)? Work could be so much more modular. It comes up again and again.